# How to debug without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, com, dll

Python -> c++ dll -> c# dll

I have a com interop c# dll that is loaded in a wrapper c++ dll throught the .tlb file generated in c# to be used in a python project. When I run in my computer it works fine but when I run in a computer that just got formated it gives:

```
WindowsError: exception code 0xe0434f4d
```

I have the redistribute c++ installed and the .net compact framework 3.5 on the formatted computer.

How can I see what is the correct exception on a computer that does not have visual studio installed? How can I debug all of this? I can't debug the dll's itself can I?

Note: in my computer all works well so maybe is some dll or file missing. I allready used  Dependency Walker to see if there's some dll missing, and nop!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the Microsoft Debugging Tools for Windows.
It contains the WinDbg debugger, which can also be used for debugging.

Advantage of WinDbg over Visual Studio is that you have much more low-level commands to find problems.

Disadvantage of WinDbg is that it's not that user friendly (compared to Visual Studio).

Comment: I can run my .exe generated from my python project in the WinDbg or OllyDbg?

Comment: Yes you can, as long as it's compiled to machine language.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) or other good applications to attach to the process or even run the application in the debugger application.

Another really good software is [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/).

Both of these will both allow you to set breakpoints on different locations in your application.

Comment: I can run my .exe generated from my python project in the WinDbg or OllyDbg?

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you initilly wrote the program in since it's compiled / converted to asm / c / machine code and then compiled as an exe.